# How to set font-size for svg without unit in javascript

Tags: javascript, css, svg, font-size

I'm editing plotly.js library source code to have scalable plots, I set viewBox and preserveAspectRatio (plotly.js use d3 library) but have problem with font-size if I use no unit the property get changed to px

I've tried to test from console if font is changed to have no unit using this:

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('text')].forEach((text) => {
    text.style.fontSize = text.style.fontSize.replace('px', '')
});
```

but it seems that if you don't use unit, the px is added automatically.

I've also tried to use rem unit and set 62.5% on html where original font size is divided by 10 but it don't scale when I resize the plot.

Also tried this new CSS typed OM API:

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('text')].forEach((text) => {
   var size = +text.style.fontSize.replace('px', '');
   text.attributeStyleMap.set('font-size', CSS.number(size))
});
```

but got error:

```
Failed to execute 'set' on 'StylePropertyMap': Invalid type for property
```

Any solution to have font-size without unit set from javascript, or other way to proportional text?

Comment: https://www.dashingd3js.com/svg-text-element this may be helpful

Comment: @UllasHunka it show how to set font-size in pixels.

Comment: try using em : https://kyleschaeffer.com/development/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SVG, having no units specifier is the same as using `px`.  So `font-size: 10` and `font-size: 10px` mean the same.  They will behave the same.

I don't know why it matters to you that the value has no units.  It sounds like you think that it is why your text is not scaling.  That will not be why. There must be something else going on.  If you want help with that problem, then add a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question.

Comment: Thanks, I've just notice that, I have `font-size-adjust` set on body with different font, that make my font-size in pixel wrong because it was using different font. Setting it to none of svg element solve my issue.

Comment: No idea why it's got down voted. It explain that the question make no sense, because you don't need to set unitless value.

Answer (score 1):

in svg each style property have corresponding attribute so you can use:

```
d3.select('text').attr('font-size', 10);
```

and it will set font-size without unit. The plot still don't scale but this was the question.